# Displaying three different states in Windows Store / WinRT in XAML with templates

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-runtime, datatemplate, contenttemplateselector

I have provided the mockups of three different forms that represent an **Employee object** when it is **null, in edit state and saved state**. I'm not using WPF or Silverlight, but **WinRT / Windows Store**.

There are few different ways to achieve this UI. The first approach is to have three different user controls. That is too much to manage when there are 10 of such entities - 30 forms to manage the state of an entity. A single usercontrol containing a **contentcontrol** with **three different data templates** and a **contenttemplateselector** is easy to manager than the previous approach.

I know **VisualStateManager** is suitable for controls whose visual state has to change based on events. Is VisualStateManager useful for a UI scenario that I described above? Or using a contentcontrol with a contenttemplateselector is the right approach to solve this?

The technical challenge is the app has numerous entities/objects and the first screen (Empty State) at least **should be reusable** for all the entities. The second and third forms can't be because they are different for every entity.

Please share your approach to this problem - **DataTemplate Vs VisualStateManager Vs Style**?

[image: Employee object in three different states]

Comment: I see someone has voted to close this question and I think this is because you are inviting personal opinions, while StackOverflow is about answering questions rather than more philosophical/opinionated chats.
I'd suggest rewording the question to keep it up.

Comment: Are you asking about whether `DataTemplate` or VSM is better for your scenario? Is this going to be more of a full-screen design or just a list item?

Comment: Yes. I'm not that familiar with VSM, so don't know whether VSM is the best for scenarios like this. This is a full-screen design. You will see only the form on the entire screen.

Answer (score 1):

Either option should work just as well, though with VSM you can get animated transitions, while with just templates - you won't.